# Suppose that $f (x, y) = xe^{−x(y+1)}$, where $0 ≤ x < ∞$, $0 ≤ y < ∞$. Find marginal densities

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, exponential-distribution

This question comes from rice 3.14

> Suppose that $$f (x, y) = xe^{−x(y+1)}$$ where  $0 ≤ x < ∞$, $0 ≤ y <
> > ∞$
>   a. Find the marginal densities of X and Y . Are X and Y independent?
>   b. Find the conditional densities of X and Y

to find the marginal densities i have integrated out $x$ and $y$ such that:

\begin{align}
f_X(x) & = \int_0^\infty xe^{−x(y+1)} dx \\
& = x \int_0^\infty  e^{−x(y+1)} dx\\
& = x \Big[ \frac{e^{−x(y+2)}}{y+2} \Big]_0^\infty\\
& = -\frac{x}{y+2} \space  \text{for} 0\leq x < \infty 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
f_Y(y) & = \int_0^\infty xe^{−x(y+1)} dy \\
\end{align}

but i get stuck here. **How to solve the integral?** **is the first marginal distribution correct?**

Answer (score 1):

$$f_Y (y)=\int_0^{\infty} xe^{-x(y+1)}dx$$ $$=-\frac x {y+1}e^{-x(y+1)}|_0^{\infty} +\frac 1 {y+1} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-x(y+1)}dx$$ $$=\frac 1{(y+1)^{2}}.$$ $f_X(x)$ is easier: $f_X (x)=\int_0^{\infty} xe^{-x(y+1)}dy=xe^{-x} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-xy} dy=e^{-x}$

Comment: could you break down the steps of how you obtaine the $f_Y(y)$. I have tries integration per partes twice, but i must be doing a mistake somewhere